# Scala Future[T] overhead heavy?

Tags: scala

I wrote a merge sort to test scala Future[T] type async calculation performance.

I have a 4 cores CPU so I expected async computation approximately 4 times faster than sync computation because I use full cpu capability (stall time should be small since the size of sub-task is the same). However the result shows that the async merge sort is slower than the normal merge sort.

Is that I wrote the concurrent badly or it is just because Future[T] overhead? Could anyone help me explain this?

```
package kai.concurrent

import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.Random

object MergeSort {
  lazy val regressThreadhold = 10000

  def mergeSortedList[T](a: Seq[T], b: Seq[T])(implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Seq[T] = {
    def loop(a: Seq[T], b: Seq[T], acc: Seq[T]): Seq[T] = {
      if (a.isEmpty && b.isEmpty) acc
      else if (a.isEmpty) b.reverse ++: acc
      else if (b.isEmpty) a.reverse ++: acc
      else if (ord.lt(a.head, b.head)) loop(a.tail, b, a.head +: acc)
      else loop(a, b.tail, b.head +: acc)
    }

    loop(a, b, Seq()).reverse
  }

  def mergeSortAsync0[T](x: Seq[T])(implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Future[Seq[T]] =
    if (x.size <= regressThreadhold) Future(mergeSort(x)) else {
      val (left, right) = x.splitAt(x.size / 2)
      val Seq(leftSorted, rightSorted) = Seq(left, right).map(seq => Future(mergeSortAsync0(seq)).flatten)
      leftSorted.zip(rightSorted).map(pair => mergeSortedList(pair._1, pair._2))
    }

  def mergeSortAsync[T](x: Seq[T])(implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Seq[T] =
    Await.result(mergeSortAsync0(x), Duration.Inf)

  def mergeSort[T](x: Seq[T])(implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Seq[T] =
    if (x.size <= 1) x else {
      val (left, right) = x.splitAt(x.size / 2)
      val (leftSorted, rightSorted) = (mergeSort(left), mergeSort(right))
      mergeSortedList(leftSorted, rightSorted)
    }
}

object MergeSortTest extends App {

  import kai.util.ProfileUtil.TimeResult

  val seq: Vector[Double] = (1 to 1000000).map(i => Random.nextDouble()).toVector
  val seqMergeSortAsync = MergeSort.mergeSortAsync(seq) withWallTimePrinted "mergeSortAsync"
  val seqMergeSort = MergeSort.mergeSort(seq) withWallTimePrinted "mergeSort"
  val seqSort = seq.sorted withWallTimePrinted "sorted"
  println(seqSort == seqMergeSort && seqMergeSort == seqMergeSortAsync)
}
```

output:

```
mergeSortAsync elapsed time: 3186 ms

mergeSort elapsed time: 3300 ms

sorted elapsed time: 581 ms

true
```

Comment: Do you average the time over multiple calls? The JVM might not be warmed up. Also make sure the code hits all cores, for example looking at activity monitor in Mac OS X.

Answer (score 5):

I've copied your test and ran it via JMH (using [sbt-jmh](https://github.com/ktoso/sbt-jmh)). I used the predefined `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` for the underlying execution context in the test.

Results:

```
[info] Benchmark                          Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
[info] MergeSortTest.benchMergeSortAsync  avgt   25  1.534 +–’ 0.212   s/op
[info] MergeSortTest.benchMergeSortSync   avgt   25  2.325 +–’ 0.437   s/op
[info] MergeSortTest.benchScalaSort       avgt   25  0.382 +–’ 0.006   s/op
```

You can see here that running the parallel version is about x1.5 faster than the sequential version, while Scala sort is x6 times faster than the sequential merge sort.

One needs to remember that when doing micro benchmarks such as these, there are many factors to take into account. It is usually best to let JMH handle the subtleties the JVM runtime has for you.

plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("pl.project13.scala" % "sbt-jmh" % "0.2.27")
```

build.sbt:

```
enablePlugins(JmhPlugin)
```

Test code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations._

import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.util.Random
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

/**
  * Created by Yuval.Itzchakov on 21/08/2017.
  */
@State(Scope.Thread)
@Warmup(iterations = 3, time = 1)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@BenchmarkMode(Array(Mode.AverageTime))
@Fork(5)
class MergeSortTest {

  var seq: Seq[Double] = _

  @Setup
  def setup(): Unit = {
    seq = (1 to 1000000).map(i => Random.nextDouble()).toVector
  }

  lazy val regressThreadhold = 10000

  def mergeSortedList[T](a: Seq[T], b: Seq[T])(implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Seq[T] = {
    def loop(a: Seq[T], b: Seq[T], acc: Seq[T]): Seq[T] = {
      if (a.isEmpty && b.isEmpty) acc
      else if (a.isEmpty) b.reverse ++: acc
      else if (b.isEmpty) a.reverse ++: acc
      else if (ord.lt(a.head, b.head)) loop(a.tail, b, a.head +: acc)
      else loop(a, b.tail, b.head +: acc)
    }

    loop(a, b, Seq()).reverse
  }

  def mergeSortAsync0[T](x: Seq[T])(implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Future[Seq[T]] =
    if (x.size <= regressThreadhold) Future(mergeSort(x)) else {
      val (left, right) = x.splitAt(x.size / 2)
      val Seq(leftSorted, rightSorted) = Seq(left, right).map(seq => Future(mergeSortAsync0(seq)).flatten)
      leftSorted.zip(rightSorted).map(pair => mergeSortedList(pair._1, pair._2))
    }

  def mergeSortAsync[T](x: Seq[T])(implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Seq[T] =
    Await.result(mergeSortAsync0(x), Duration.Inf)

  def mergeSort[T](x: Seq[T])(implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Seq[T] =
    if (x.size <= 1) x else {
      val (left, right) = x.splitAt(x.size / 2)
      val (leftSorted, rightSorted) = (mergeSort(left), mergeSort(right))
      mergeSortedList(leftSorted, rightSorted)
    }

  @Benchmark
  def benchMergeSortSync(): Unit = {
    mergeSort(seq)
  }

  @Benchmark
  def benchMergeSortAsync(): Unit = {
    mergeSortAsync(seq)
  }

  @Benchmark
  def benchScalaSort(): Unit = {
    seq.sorted
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much!